# yes/No Is $f_n(x) =\frac{x^2}{x^2 + (1-nx)^2}$ uniformly convergent on $[0,1]?$

Tags: real-analysis

Is $f_n(x) =\frac{x^2}{x^2 + (1-nx)^2}$ uniformly convergent on $[0,1]?$ Yes/No

My attempt :  I found the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2104129/f-nx-fracx2x21-nx2-is-uniformly-convergent-on-delta-1-for-al).In answer it is written that $f_n(x)$  is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$

But my answer  is **No**

Take$ M_n =\sup_{[0,1]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|$

Now put $x=\frac{1}{n}\in[0,1]$.Then

$ M_n =\sup_{[0,1]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|1-0|=1\neq0$

This implies $f_n(x) $ is not uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$

Im confused   whether $f_n(x) $ is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$ or not ?

Comment: It helps if you state what $f(x)$ is.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews    $ f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)=0$

Comment: @jasmine It is clearly not uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$ as you have shown. In your link, the uniform convergence is shown over $[\delta,1]$ for all $0<\delta<1$.

Comment: Yes, but it is worth stating $f(x)=0$ in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other question and answers only prove that it is uniformly convergent on $[\delta,1]$ for any $0<\delta<1.$

It is not uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$ for exactly the reason you’ve mentioned.

In $[\delta,1]$ there are only finitely many $\frac{1}{n},$ so they are not a problem as $n\to\infty.$